# Filling up the rows by comparing with previous records in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I Have a data set like given below

```
id Subid  updateType   T-id  updateTime     createTime

1  7393   TOP-UP       2313  2015-10-01     2015-10-01
2  7393   TOP-UPDATE   NULL  2015-10-03     2015-10-03 
3  7393   CDR          NULL  2015-10-04     2015-10-04
4  7393   EXP_By_Date  NULL  2015-10-05     2015-10-05 
5  7393   TOP-UP       2456  2015-11-01     2015-11-01
6  7393   TOP-UPDATE   NULL  2015-11-03     2015-11-03 
7  7393   CDR          NULL  2015-11-04     2015-11-04
8  7393   CDR          NULL  2015-11-04     2015-11-04
9  7393   EXP_By_Date  NULL  2015-11-05     2015-11-05
```

The data set has T-id only for updateType being TOP-UP, and rest of T-id's being NULL, I want to populate rest of the records with T-ids where the updateType='EXP_By_Date' from previous top-up T-ids, how to achieve this in MySQL

The desired output would be

```
id Subid  updateType   T-id  updateTime     createTime

1  7393   TOP-UP       2313  2015-10-01     2015-10-01
2  7393   TOP-UPDATE   2313  2015-10-03     2015-10-03 
3  7393   CDR          2313  2015-10-04     2015-10-04
4  7393   EXP_By_Date  2313  2015-10-05     2015-10-05 
5  7393   TOP-UP       2456  2015-11-01     2015-11-01
6  7393   TOP-UPDATE   2456  2015-11-03     2015-11-03 
7  7393   CDR          2456  2015-11-04     2015-11-04
8  7393   CDR          2456  2015-11-04     2015-11-04
9  7393   EXP_By_Date  2456  2015-11-05     2015-11-05
```

Regards

Comment: How do you define `previous`. If possible add the expected output.

Comment: Pick the max tid with an id less than the exp_by_date in each case